# Auth dialog asks for extended permissions, but my app doesn't need them. How do I prevent the auth dialog from showing the second page?

Tags: permissions, facebook-authentication

I set up an app to allow users to log into my site using Facebook. When users click the FB login button, the expected auth dialog appears. My auth dialog shows a second page which says: "This app may post on your behalf, including status updates, photos and more."

But my app doesn't need any extended permissions, and will not be posting anything to Facebook. I don't want this second page to appear, but I can't figure out how to make it go away.

On my app's settings page, I didn't specify any extended permissions. Is there someplace else I have to specify that I don't want extended permissions?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You might have specified a scope in the "Login with Facebook" button that requests these permissions from the user. Especially if you just copy-and-pasted an example from the documentation, this might have happened.

Check in your HTML whether you have something similar to this:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" scope="publish_stream">
    Login with Facebook
</div>
```

If so, make sure to get rid of the `scope` attribute.

Comment: If that's not a problem at all, some code from your login page could help with answering your question.